# Mockito - check if NO method was called on an object(object was not accessed)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to write a test that passes a mock object A into an object under test B and checks if ANY of the methods of A were called. To give some context, class B is designed to manipulate A in a specific way, based on a set of parameters, and under certain conditions it shouldn't do anything to it at all. So my goal is to test that scenario. I know how to test whether a specific method was called or not:

```
verify(A, never()).myMethod();
```

But I can't find a way to make sure that NONE of the methods A has were called. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that [`verifyNoInteractions`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoInteractions-java.lang.Object...-) might be what you're looking for.  In your case you'd call `Mockito.verifyNoInteractions(A)`.

`public static void verifyNoInteractions(java.lang.Object... mocks)`

```
Verifies that no interactions happened on given mocks.
```

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoInteractions-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: So I should just call Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(A)  ?

Comment: Yup, that should do it.

Comment: Hey you're right, it totally works! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Method verifyZeroInteraction is depricated since version 3.0.1., please use verifyNoInteractions instead.